# Returning the contents of an ArrayList index based on if scanner input matches a word inside same index

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I am wanting to return the contents of an ArrayList index based on if a scanner input matches any of the words inside said index.

So if ArrayList index 0 contains

```
<dog, cat, mouse>`
```

and index 1 contains

```
<football, baseball, rugby>
```

and `scanner input = "football"`,

Index 1 in it's entirety should be printed.

However, I am unsure on how to do this so any advice would be fantastic.

Edit:

The code below reads the file where I am getting the data from and stores each separate line as an index.

```
while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
            editList.add(fileScanner.nextLine());
        }
```

The code below reads the input and if editScanner input is found inside the editList, then the index should be printed. However, i know this is incorrect but I am totally unsure on how to print the contents of the index as a String

```
 if (editList.contains(editScanner)) {
                        while (((edit = fileReader.readLine()) != null)) {
                            String chosenFilm = editList.indexOf(editScanner);
                        }
```

Comment: Your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks

Comment: You'd better post some code, to see what you tried

Comment: Did you already have tried to write this ? Do you know how to store those values in a `List` ? Do you know how to read from a `Scanner` ? Can you explain what you mean by "_how to do this so any advice would be fantastic._", in java we don't have to care about "devices", the JVM run "the same" everywhere. **That's a lot of question but you don't have even one for the moment.**

Answer (score 0):

Make your list an arraylist of sets, in this way:

```
 List<Set<String>> yourList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then to check if you've to print an index because it has football on it just do

```
 yourList.get(i).contains("football")
```

If you can't repeat football on various indexes, use a Map instead, using football as the key and the index football is in as the value. Then you can check the index and print that index from the list directly.

Comment: What would "i" be defined as, surely that's the index if I'm correct?

Comment: Yes, i would be the index. By the way this is a faster, more logical implementation than the other answer (using sublists). You clearly have one set of strings in each index, not a sublist. The reason sets are faster is in a HashSet you use dictionary access time using hash codes (constant time) vs checking all the sublist indexes string by string (n time).

Answer (score 0):

Considering your structure is a `List<List<String>>` and `input` :

```
List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(Arrays.asList("dog", "cat", "mouse"));
list.add(Arrays.asList("football", "baseball", "rugby"));

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = sc.nextLine();
```

---

You can do as follow

1. Iterate over the different `subLists` and find the good one (stop when you find)

   ```
   int index = -1;
   for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {     // iterate
       if (list.get(i).contains(input)) {      // check if present
           index = i;                          // keep index
           break;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Using `Streams`

   ```
   index = list.stream()                       // iterate
               .filter(l -> l.contains(input)) // keep sublist where present
               .mapToInt(list::indexOf)        // transform it to its index
               .findFirst()                    // keep index
               .orElse(-1);                    // if not found return -1
   ```